# i have a problem with my domain getting rederected to another one

Tags: server, domain

My website that i did via wordpress named graff34.fr is getting getting constantly rederected to graffiti34.art another domain that i openned but i deleted it from wordpress domain section 
and now whatever domain name i type it won't connect and says me domain is parked.
by the way graffiti34.fr works perfectly well on my cellphone thanks for helping me have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

it's working(not redirecting),
you may be getting the error because of DNS update DNS may need several hours to fully update